# Simulink Test Assessment For Pulse Detection (Button Press)

Tags: matlab, testing, signal-processing, simulink, formal-verification

I am new to Simulink Test, and I need some help.

I have a model that I am trying to test with a test assessment block.  The model is meant to do the following:

1. When a button is pressed for >= 70ms, the model will assert a 62.5 pulse on the output.
2. If the button is pressed for < 70ms, the model will not do anything (output remains 0).
   The model works fine.  I have 2 test sequences.  The first presses the button for < 70ms, and we get no output.  I can write the assessment for that test case without issue.
   However, detecting the output pulse, with a conditional of >= 70ms is proving difficult.  I am trying to do all of this in the test manager, so I can run a report at the end showing the switch debounce model works.
   Does anyone have any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYnsa.png)

I have tried many different verify statement mixed with time (haschanged, elapsed, if, else, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/use-timers-in-asynchronous-tasks.html)

[And this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/create-a-customized-asynchronous-library.html#f24730)

You're doing to want to implement a timer that calls a function to emit the desire pulse once the timer runs out. Letting go of the button should stop the timer, and pressing the button should start it.